# Tensorflow 2.0 on Intel 620 GPU

Tags: gpu, tensorflow2.0

I've been reading through multiple stack posts, papers, and git issues trying to find if you HAVE to have a NVIDIA in order to run tensorflow GPU? I personally have a Intel UHD Graphics 620, but I know that I cannot use the CUDA toolkit with it. I was wondering if there was any up to date support on this or if I am just SOL?

Comment: Based on the Tensorflow documentation at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu it indicates a CUDA architecture is required, which is a NVIDIA creation.  Also, if you accept wikipedia, the list of GPUs supporting CUDA ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported ) are all NVIDIA.

Comment: CUDA is proprietary to Nvidia. It cannot be used with other GPUs.